# Is there any way to get current directory using only javascript and without regular expressions?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get only the current directory (the directory containing the webpage in use), without using regular expressions to breakdown the url?

Comment: The current directory of what?  Depending on how your URL is formed, this could be a bit tricky (URL re-writing etc)

Comment: How can you get current directory from url?

Comment: You could get the current directory from the url if you're not using url rewrite by calling window.location.href and using regular expressions to get the last directory within the reference. But I want to know is there a way to directly call the current directory using javascript.

Comment: For commandline use: `if (typeof process != 'undefined') { process.stdout.write('Current dir is ' + process.cwd() + '\n') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
 var urlChunks = location.href.split('/');
 alert(urlChunks[urlChunks.length - 1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SEXnh/5/

Comment: if you don't want all the parameters (which I think is what is being asked) then try var urlChunks = location.pathname(split"/"); instead

Comment: @JeremyQuick It does not use regEx its using regular javascript functions .

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is what you are looking for but

```
location.host
```

or

```
location.pathname
```

might give you what you are looking for.
If so check this out for more on the location object
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

No.  A web page, when loaded in a browser, does not have a directory.  It has a URL (the path that the browser followed to get the web page) but that URL is not necessarily related in any way to the path structure in which the original html page is stored on the server that processed the request.

Comment: But all relative paths used in the web page are relative to the "directory" where the HTML file is...

Comment: That is only true of the simplest web site.  Look at the URL of this very StackOverflow question.  Do you believe that the HTML for this page is being served from a folder anywhere on the web server with a relative name of `questions/12823110/is-there-any-way-to-get-current-directory-using-only-javascript-and-without-regu`?  I doubt it.

Comment: You are right. But all relative paths (for example "img/logo.png") will still use this "directory" (not a real directory) as a starting point. For my example it would be `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823110/is-there-any-way-to-get-current-directory-using-only-javascript-and-without-regu/img/logo.png`

Comment: That path, also, may not correspond in any way to a folder structure on the server.  That logo.png could be served out of a database or even potentially created on the fly by the server.  It *does not* necessarily live in a folder called `img`.  That is why I have to repeat **the URL is not necessarily related in any way to the path structure** on the server.